# Use ASIO with Gervill Synthesizer in Java

Tags: java, javasound, synthesizer, asio, gervill

I am using Gervill's software synthesizer to load an SF2 soundbank, and play music from a Midi keyboard, and I was wondering if it's possible to play the output through ASIO, probably through [JAsioHost](https://github.com/mhroth/jasiohost). I've been trying to look through the Gervill source code to find when the raw audio data is actually passed to the audio driver, but I can't seem to find it, and even then, I'm not sure whether that is the correct way to go about it.

The chain I am using is using an SF2loader to load a soundfont into the default synthesizer, which I then play notes on with the channel noteOn methods.

Comment: Does Gervil send out raw audio? If so, first place I'd look is for an invocation of javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine. Or does Gervil output MIDI? If it is driving a MIDI keyboard, I'd expect the latter, not raw audio. I've never used Gervil (though heard of it) so my comment may be useless.

Comment: It does output raw audio, and I've looked for the implementations of the SourceDataLine, but that just seems to give the audio to the mixer, and I can't find where that is invoked.

Comment: Are you familiar with the process of inspecting the mixer to see what lines are available? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html I'm still not understanding the chain that you have. Maybe others can figure it out, but I need things to me more explicit if I'm going to be able to contribute anything.